# How to print array of numbers given i and j, such that sum of all elements of i is equal to j?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given the numbers `i` and `j`.
Print an array of length `i` such that the sum of all the elements in the array is equal `j`.

input:

```
  i = 5 ;
  j = 27;
```

Output:

```
  6
  6
  5
  5
  5
```

like:

```
a[0] = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
a[1] = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
a[2] = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
a[3] = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
a[4] = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

my code:-

```
int N, K;
cin >> N >> K;
int arr[N]{ 0 };
while (K > 0)
{
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < N; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        k++;
        arr[i] = k;
    }
    K--;
}
```

Comment: will 0 0 0 0 27 be a good solution for you? ;) I guess not, so you have to clarity more...

Comment: It should match the pattern of output.

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking the question ?

Comment: yeah but it is giving 1 1 1 1 1 as output.

Comment: What is the pattern?

Comment: like a[0] = 6,a[1] =6,a[2] = 5,a[3] = 5,a[4] = 5

Comment: That's an example, not a rule. Explain the pattern. Is `5 5 5 6 6` a solution? Is `0 0 0 0 27` a solution? Is `6 6 5 5 5` the only solution?

Comment: like for 8 and 35 it should be  5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4

Comment: well both are accepted but not 0 0 0 0 27.

Comment: Is `1 1 1 1 23` accepted?

Comment: Nope that's not acceptable.

Comment: `int arr[N] {0};` is not valid c++. C++ doesn't support VLA. It's a compiler feature.

Comment: I always thought that it initialize all the array elements to 0. thanks

Comment: @user552695 Think about this. If you can explain the rule behind the pattern that you are seeking then you are half way to solving the problem. Programming is specifiying precise rules to solve problems. I know you know what you want intuitively, but that's not enough to be a programmer.

Comment: got it  @john you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide `j` by `i`. You could print `i` times `j / i` but the sum is too small. The difference between `j` and `i * (j / i)` is the number of time you have to print `(j / i) + 1`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 5, j = 27;
    int s = j / i;
    int k = j - s * i;
    bool first = true;
    for (int z = 0; z < k; ++z) {
        if (!first) std::cout << ' ';
        else first = false;
        std::cout << s + 1;
    }
    for (int z = k; z < i; ++z) {
        if (!first) std::cout << ' ';
        else first = false;
        std::cout << s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```